# How can I store an encryption key outside version control in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

I need to use encryption on private/personal user data. I am going to use the following encryption library.

[RbNaCL](https://github.com/crypto-rb/rbnacl/wiki/SimpleBox)

I need a way to store the KEY outside of version control so I can run the app locally. When pushing the code to our hosting company I can put the KEY in the server env variables. Just not sure how and the best way to do it locally.

I should note that all developers working on the project use the same database so we all need the same KEY for development and staging environment.

https://www.happybearsoftware.com/how-to-actually-do-a-cryptography-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is how to keep a .env out of version control while in the repository, people collaborating should know about the what are the enviroment variables. Normally .env-sample (which is a dumy in which all variables are kept without values) is tracked and while .env is ignored (by adding it in .gitignore in case of git)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, secrets never get committed to repositories. Just put them in a config file (like `config.yaml` or `secrets.xml` or `env.sh` or similar); copy the file (to something like `config.yaml.example` or `secrets-skel.xml` or `env.sh.sample`); put the first one into `.gitignore` (or equivalent, if you're a non-Git heretic), and replace all the secrets in the second one with placeholders. Commit the second one so that everyone who checks out the project will know the format that they should have; but the secret one never touches the repository. If you need to share keys between developers, do it in another way (from IRC/Slack/Email to encrypted USB storage device, depending on how confidential the stuff is).

If you go with YAML-ish kind of solution, in code you can try to find the file, if it is absent then use environment, or vice versa - look up environment, if no variable is there look for the config file to read from (and possibly even stuff it into `ENV` so you don't need another config object; you might do it in `config/application.rb` kind of thing. If you go with `env.sh` kind of approach, you can declare environment variables directly; when you need to start developing, you can `source env.sh` (or shorter `. env.sh`) to set them up.

Answer (score 0):

> *I should note that all developers working on the project use the same database so we all need the same KEY for development and staging environment.*

Store the key, and any other shared secrets, in a secure shared vault. Many password managers provide shared vaults, such as [1Password](https://support.1password.com/create-share-vaults/) or [LastPass](https://teams.lastpass.com/shared-folders/).

Then each developer can copy the key from the shared vault and set it in their development environment.